# How to add or remove attributes in laravel eloquent by condition on request

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have Post model with many post types. I need to control with post attributes by post type. For example I have 2 post types:

- Song
- Singer

Model only once **Post**.

Post model scheme:

```
id
title
description
parent_id
type
```

When requesting `song` post type, how I can add attribute `singer` to response array automatically or when requesting `singer` post type add attribute `songs`?

I tired inside model ussing `__construct()` method but not work:

```
public function __construct() {
    if($this->type == "song") {
        //$this->with = array_push($this->with, "singer");
        $this->appends = array_push($this->appends, 'singer');
    }
}
```

Comment: *"how I can add attribute"* - what have you tried?

Comment: Show us some code, how do you exactly `return` your data

Comment: I meant, you send data from server somewhere? Do you use it in the blade or so? `__construct()` has nothing to do with the final data representation

Comment: Yes I wiil send from server when come API request @Tarasovych

Comment: How do you response for API request? Not by using constructor, I guess

Comment: I use `__construct` inside my model. It's simple when a certain type of post is asked, I must return in response the necessary attributes using the model.

Comment: I will not do anything on the controller in my case @Tarasovych

Answer (score 1):

```
public function __construct() {
   parent::__construct()
    if($this->type == "song") {
        //$this->with = array_push($this->with, "singer");
        $this->appends = array_push($this->appends, 'singer');
    }
}
```